# Can I increase azure linux vms tcp keep alive timeout if not using load balancer?

Tags: sockets, tcp, timeout, azure-virtual-machine, keep-alive

I've Azure VM running Linux(ubuntu 18.06). I'm running Python socket server there. Now the problem is, any socket client which is not doing any activity for 4 minutes is getting disconnected. I've gone through https://github.com/wbuchwalter/azure-content/blob/master/includes/guidance-tcp-session-timeout-include.md and changed /etc/sysctl.conf on my linux instance, but it's not  working. Now my question is,
1. Is it possible to change keepalive with default public ip of azre vm, because the link says "outbound using SNAT (Source NAT). This timeout is set to 4 minutes, and cannot be adjusted."

Answer (score 1):

Inbound TCP timeout for Public IP can be controlled. For outbound, the default value is 4 minutes and cannot be changed. You an still keep the session active by sending keep-alive packets.